# Why would a wrist watch lose power just weeks after replacing the battery?

Tags: batteries

I have a CASIO watch that required a battery replacement 6 years after I got it as a new watch. Now, the replacement battery, a CR2025 cell, was installed by a jeweler and lasted 3 months. Nothing was wrong with the power supply for the 3 months. When the replacement battery stopped keeping the watch running, it may have happened while the watch was lying down, off of my wrist. Just a few weeks ago, the same watch lost power supply after taking it off before taking a shower. This time, the screen went blank, a month after the battery was replaced. No timers were on at the time. What could be the cause of this occurring? Could the problem be related to the contact between the battery cell and the connection inside the watch being loose?

Comment: Bad battery holder spring?

Comment: The shopkeeper tells me that good quality battery from a reputed manufacturer will last longer than no-name ones. It maybe observation bias, but I agree with it; and not just for watches. Have you checked the battery after taking it out ?

Comment: The watch may have developed an issue where it's drawing more power than it's supposed to and draining the battery prematurely.

Comment: A broad question asking for speculations. There maybe a 100 reasons. For eg: Shopkeeper cheated u with a used battery.

Comment: You don't need online shopping from dodgy sites to get bad batteries. I recently bought a card of 5 good name branded CR2032's from a well known high street supermarket because they very priced as a 'very good deal'. When I measured their internal resistance (the standard way to measure state of charge for coin cells, see the manfacturer's data) I found three were nearly end of life, and the other two were not new. I doubt the supermarket bought old cells and repackaged them, but somehow they managed to put rubbish on the shelves.

Answer (score 1):

CR2025 is just the physical size of the battery, but you have many different types of batteries: lithium, alkaline, etc.

Lithium itself has different chemistry as well, some batteries are also designed for higher current delivery or low self-discharge, and so forth.

Also, there is a lot of "fake" or "old" batteries. The battery you got probably was of bad quality, old or defective.

When getting the battery, make sure to order from a reliable source (not eBay, not amazon) and check the capacity (mAh) and make sure it's a low self-discharge battery.